# Good cheap mouse for double clicking and can be purchased in India

Tags: gaming, mice

I was thinking of purchasing a new mouse, since my current mouse is not working properly. I was thinking of getting a mouse that is lightweight and can double click. I would prefer that it can drag click as well, but it is not compulsory to be able to do so.
In short,
Qualities the mouse should have :

**Lightweight**

**can double click**

**can be purchased in India and is under 50$**

I have found a mouse that is lightweight but I can't find any help online so as to if it can drag click or double click. [This (Redragon m908)](https://www.amazon.in/redragon-Impact-Buttons-Precision-programmable/dp/B07HC4NBQ8/ref=sr_1_4?crid=QPIIVF5ZBFZ9&keywords=redragon%20m908&qid=1651301492&s=computers&sprefix=redragon%20m90%2Ccomputers%2C213&sr=1-4) is the mouse I am talking about. Can anyone recommend me such a mouse, or tell me if the Redragon mouse can double click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, double clicking and dragging are software features, not hardware features, so as long as the mouse is consistent with its clicks (and your OS supports it), you can double click and drag click. This means you should get a mouse with good reviews, and you are probably good with double clicks as well.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, The G502 hero should also be able to double click, but it actually can't. No offense, but I doubt what you said is true or not...

Comment: That mouse uses inconsistent switches according to Reddit, that double click when a single click is needed.

Comment: Could you please link the reddit page from which you read this?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/LogitechG/comments/cxm3vh/g502_hero_double_click_issue/

Comment: @RyugaGod What makes you think the G502 hero can't double-click? Of course it can: if you click twice fast on *any* mouse, it double clicks. Unless the mouse has a hardware problem. Or, if by "can double click" you mean "can simulate a double click with a single click of a special button", then you should be more explicit.

Comment: @dim I assume the OP is speaking about gaming mice, some of which are capable of simulating two clicks with one mouse click or "drag clicking" where you click very quickly by "dragging" a finger along the mouse button so that the vibrations cause clicks to register.

Comment: I was unclear with my questioning, I was indeed looking for wat @dim says, a gaming mouse than can simulate a double click with a single. I found the hyperx pulsefire which does so.